# reorder factor levels by data in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose I have a factor whose levels are

`"1/1/2013"  "1/1/2014"  "1/1/2015"  "10/1/2012" "10/1/2013" "10/1/2014" "4/1/2013"  "4/1/2014"  "4/1/2015"  "7/1/2012"  "7/1/2013"  "7/1/2014"`

What is the easiest way to resort this by date? I know I can do this manually by picking and choosing...

Thanks!

Comment: I would convert to `Date` class and then use `order` or `sort`. i..e `sort(as.Date(yourvec,  '%d/%m/%Y'))`  But, your description is not clear

Comment: You need to make the class dates or use a difference character format like "YYYY-MM-DD". The date class solution is safer though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will sort the levels of the factor so that plotting will make sense, but ordinary factors do not really have an order. For there to really be order, i.e. for there to be a less-than or greater-than relationship between items, you would need to define an "ordered" factor (see `?factor`):

```
> fac <- factor(c( "1/1/2013",  "1/1/2014",  "1/1/2015",  "10/1/2012", "10/1/2013" ,"10/1/2014", "4/1/2013",  "4/1/2014" , "4/1/2015" , "7/1/2012",  "7/1/2013",  "7/1/2014") )
> levels(fac) <- levels(fac)[ order( as.Date(levels(fac), format="%m/%d/%Y") )]
> fac
 [1] 7/1/2012  10/1/2012 1/1/2013  4/1/2013  7/1/2013  10/1/2013
 [7] 1/1/2014  4/1/2014  7/1/2014  10/1/2014 1/1/2015  4/1/2015 
12 Levels: 7/1/2012 10/1/2012 1/1/2013 4/1/2013 ... 4/1/2015
```

Now the levels will display in the order you expect:

```
> levels(fac)
 [1] "7/1/2012"  "10/1/2012" "1/1/2013"  "4/1/2013"  "7/1/2013" 
 [6] "10/1/2013" "1/1/2014"  "4/1/2014"  "7/1/2014"  "10/1/2014"
[11] "1/1/2015"  "4/1/2015"
```

But if there are repeated elements, then the levels will be shorter than the factor vector itself and they are still not "in order" in the vector itself, ... because it's not an ordered factor. It would make a lot more sense to convert that vector to `Date`-class.

Or you could ignore all my advice and just do what you asked to do:

```
> fac[ order( as.Date(fac, format="%m/%d/%Y") )]
 [1] 7/1/2012  10/1/2012 1/1/2013  4/1/2013  7/1/2013  10/1/2013
 [7] 1/1/2014  4/1/2014  7/1/2014  10/1/2014 1/1/2015  4/1/2015 
12 Levels: 1/1/2013 1/1/2014 1/1/2015 10/1/2012 ... 7/1/2014
```